# EntityFramework - Erro table or view does not exist

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Tenho uma tabela no oracle que so pode ser acessada desta forma sms."Usuario", ao fazer o mapeamento da entidade, fiz desta forma:

```cs
builder.ToTable("sms.Usuario")
```

Ao executar o projeto e ver o log, vejo que o EF gera desta forma para mim

```sql
FROM "sms.Usuario"
```

Desta forma, causa um erro de 'tabela não existe'.

Como eu faço para solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conheço bem Oracle, mas traçando um paralelo para o SQL server, diria que a notação correta seria

```sql
... FROM "sms"."Usuario"
```

Onde `Usuario` é a tabela e `sms` é o DB schema.

Sendo assim, é preciso alterar o overload usado na configuração do entity framework para

```cs
ToTable("Usuario", "sms")
```

Comment: eu sabia q estava fazendo da forma errada, pq eu ja precisei fazer isso a uns anos atrás, mas havia esquecido e também não lembrava como isso chamava (DB Schema)... Agradeço muito a ajuda :)